# yum update fails

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

```
i have RHEL 6.3

[root@RHEL6 yum.repos.d]# uname -a
Linux RHEL6.3-64-BuildMac 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 13 18:24:36 EDT 2012     x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My /etc/yum.conf looks like  
[main]  
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever  
keepcache=0  
debuglevel=2  
logfile=/var/log/yum.log  
exactarch=1  
obsoletes=1  
gpgcheck=1  
plugins=1  
installonly_limit=3  
reposdir=/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel.repo

The contents of my /etc.yum.repo.d/rhel.repo looks like
[rhelrepo]  
name=my rhel repo  
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/  
#gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6  
enabled=1  
gpgcheck=0
```

But my yum update fails with the following error

```
[root@RHEL6 yum.repos.d]# yum update  
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

please could somebody help

Answer (score 1):

Disable [subscription manager](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unable-to-read-consumer-identity-rhn-yum-warning/) and try

Change enable=0 in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/product-id.conf and /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf

> [main]
>
> enabled=0

and then clean cache

> rm -rfv /var/cache/yum/*
>
> yum clean all

Comment: Mine was hanging at "updating certificate-based repositories", and this solution worked for me, thanks. Note that I did not have an active RHEL subscription on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help.  I haven't had this error myself, though, so I couldn't test.

http://lpar.ath0.com/2012/09/10/yum-unable-to-read-consumer-identity/

Comment: sorry it does not help!!

Answer (score 0):

RHEL requires that you identify yourself as a legitimate customer for updates, and the error message you posted seems to say that failed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "Unable to read consumer identity" warning:

```
$ vi /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf
```

Then change enabled to 0 so the file looks like this:

```
[main]
enabled=0
```

Then your "Unable to read consumer identity" warning will go away. Also, your update probably was not failing, there were probably just no packages to update at the time. Leaving it with the warning is fine too, it has no functional impact.